# how to print the numbers divisible by 3?

Tags: java

I want to print number divisible by 3.I have written this program but can't figure out 
that why it's not printing the numbers divisible by 3.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DivisibleByThree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int beginning = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        int end = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        divisibleByThreeInRange(beginning,end);   
    }

    public static void divisibleByThreeInRange(int beginning, int end) {
        int i = beginning;
        while(i <= end) {
            if(i%3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                i++;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What happens if the first number isn't divisible by 3?

Comment: Save yourself some time by replacing `i++` with `i += 3`. If i is divisible by 3, it is mathematically guaranteed that i+1 and i+2 will not be divisible by 3.

Answer (score 3):

Just move the counter outside the if the condition

```
   while(i <= end) {
        if(i%3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Because you need to increase the value of `i` also if `i` is not divisible by 3

Answer (score 0):

Increment **i** outside the if block